# Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'chart.js' resolves to an untyped module at '/src/chart.js', which cannot be augmented

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, angular7, ng2-charts

I'm creating barchart using ng2-chart library for charts. I got the following error while `ng serve`:

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/types/index.d.ts(5,16): error
>   TS2665: Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'chart.js'
>   resolves to an untyped module at
>   '/node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js', which cannot be augmented.

I want some datalabels on barchart.

So I added 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels' in component.

When I add following lines in my code, this error occurs.

```
import * as pluginDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';

export class AnalysisComponent implements OnInit {
    public barChartPlugins = [pluginDataLabels];
}
```

Version of libraries

```
"chart.js": "^2.7.3",
"ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
"chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^0.6.0",
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using old libraries? `ng2-charts` is at 2.2.0 now and `chart.js` is at 2.8.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per [this comment](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/pull/121#issuecomment-473327301) you have to install @types/chart.js.
And you have to import this lib with

```
import * as Chart from 'chart.js';
```

Comment: Installing @types/chart.js solved my issue. Thanks a lot.